# How to reference a Laravel route in my View so that if I change the route, I will not have to update all my Views?

Tags: php, url, routes, laravel, laravel-4

Consider the following simple example:

```
// routes.php 

  // You can get this route by http://localhost/adminpanel/home ...users...etc
  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'adminpanel', 'before' => 'auth'), function(){
      Route::resource('home', 'Admin\Controllers\HomeController');
      Route::resource('users', 'Admin\Controllers\UsersController');
  });


// Admin\Views\users.php
  <!-- I do not want to update this everytime I change the route -->
  <a href="<?=URL::to('adminpanel/home');?>">Click here to go home</a>
```

If I change **adminpanel** to something else in my *routes.php* I will also have to change every View that used it. 
**Is there another way I can reference the route in my Views or is there any other good strategy I can implement from Laravel naturally?** 
Otherwise I'm thinking I might need to add some sort of CONSTANT variable to my *global.php* to possibly accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the route 'as' parameter to give a name to your route:

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'));
```

Then you just have to

```
<a href="<?=URL::route('profile');?>">Click here to go home</a>
```

Using your resource routes, you can list them

```
php artisan routes
```

And use the name of the route, third column.

Using your example, you'll have 2 base routes: home and users, this is the list for the home resources:

```
+--------+----------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                  | Name         | Action                                   | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+----------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET home             | home.index   | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@index   |                |               |
|        | GET home/create      | home.create  | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@create  |                |               |
|        | POST home            | home.store   | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@store   |                |               |
|        | GET home/{home}      | home.show    | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@show    |                |               |
|        | GET home/{home}/edit | home.edit    | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@edit    |                |               |
|        | PUT home/{home}      | home.update  | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@update  |                |               |
|        | PATCH home/{home}    |              | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@update  |                |               |
|        | DELETE home/{home}   | home.destroy | Admin\Controllers\HomeController@destroy |                |               |
+--------+----------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

So you'll build that route using:

```
<a href="<?=URL::route('home.index');?>">Click here to go home</a>
```

Note that the your group prefix `adminpanel` won't be added to your routes names and you don't have to use it. What you need to create your routes is the exact name the command `artisan routes` shows in `Name` column.

Using Blade you can just do

```
{{ link_to_route('home.index', 'Click here to go home') }}
```

Much cleaner, right?

Comment: Antonio can you rewrite my example implementing your solution to make sure I understand you correctly? Notice I'm also using a route group and filter.

Comment: @DavidGraham these are called named routes: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: Just edited to give you an example using your resouceful routes.

Comment: So you are saying I don't have to reference the route group at all in my View? I can just name the routes that are inside the group (using `as`) or if they are resources I can call them as you've shown? Am I right?

Comment: You don't, groups will not be appended to your routes names. But there are some folks asking for them to be added.

Comment: Ok last request, maybe you can mention that in your answer as well: "that you don't have to use the group in the View if the routes inside..." to help others like me understand fully. Thanks so much @AntonioCarlosRibeiro Accepting your answer now!!

Comment: +1 @AntonioCarlosRibeiro going above and beyond! I like the `link_to_route` call. I'm not sold on templates just yet (I consider myself part of the "PHP is the templating language" camp) but will likely use that helper.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your problem would be to use named routes like Antonio suggested.
You could also use the link_to_route helper to generate a full HTML link to the named route.

More information about url helpers can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls

More information about named routes can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: +1 Thanks, I hadn't made it to the URL helpers yet. Been busy still setting things up. `link_to_route` looks very useful. Appreciate it!